# An error occurred while making the HTTP request to https

Tags: .net, asmx

I have asmx web service in .Net framework 4.6 that consumes https web service. Here is the below code I have before calling the service:

`System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;`

It works fine in debug mode. I can view the data that is expected but when running the application in release mode or without debugging in vs2017, I am getting the below error:

```
Web ServiceSystem.ServiceModel.CommunicationException:  
An error occurred while making the HTTP request to https://externalwebservice address. 
This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly 
with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the 
security binding between the client and the server. 
---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: 
An unexpected error occurred on a send. 
---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection:   
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. 
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed  
by the remote host.
```

I got a self-signed certificate installed in IIS.

I am really confused on it works in debug mode but not in release.
Please help.

Comment: Get `Ssl3` out of there. It's obsolete and dangerous. And for that matter base `Tls` and and `Tls11` shouldn't be used anymore, either. You want 1.2 or 1.3 now. This **might** even fix the issue, as offering those old insecure protocols, in combination with other tactics to eventually force the downgrade, is one tactic used by hackers, and some servers will outright reject if you even make it available.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I made the change still not working.